# Automating the lm() function object not found error

Tags: r, lm

```
test <- function(y, x)
{
  b <- paste(x, collapse=" + ")
  df.ols <- lm(paste(y," ~ ",b))
  uhatols <- df.ols$res
  c <- paste("uhatols ~ x[1]")
  df.aux2 <- lm(c)
}
x <- data.frame(e=c(1,4,13,2,7,6), f=c(5,9,1,4,3,2))
y <- data.frame(y=c(3,19,1,7,0.2,18))
test(y,x)
```

I am trying to automate a few ols regressions. I keep getting the error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'uhatols' not found` (in the last line) when I run this formula. Could anyone please tell me why?

Comment: Please explain exactly what your function is supposed to do.

Comment: @Roland First, OLS regression of y on all variables in x. Then OLS regression of the residuals of this regression on the first regressor in x.

Comment: `c` should be of class `formula`. You also made the mistake of including `x[1]` as part of the string. Try `c <- as.formula(paste("uhatols ~", x[1]))`. Also, be careful when using variable names that also happen to be function names. In this case, `c` is similar to the function `c()`.

Comment: @laterow Thank you, that works :)! Why is it that I did not have to do as.formula() for my df.ols statement in the second line while it is necessary here?

Comment: Run the code line by line and check what the content is of both formulas, you'll see :) If you do see what is wrong with both of them, you'll understand why it is good practice to use `as.formula` if you want to use a formula (or `update.formula` if you want to get fancy).

Comment: @Laterow Thanks but I don't really get the difference. For first regression I get `"uhatols ~  c(1, 4, 13, 2, 7, 6)"` as the formula, and for the second (without the `as.formula()`) I get `"c(3, 19, 1, 7, 0.2, 18) ~ c(1, 4, 13, 2, 7, 6) + c(5, 9, 1, 4, 3, 2)"`. What is the difference that you meant?

Comment: @Laterow I can see that the `as.formula` format removes the quotes and changes the datatype, but I mean, I didn't do that for `df.ols` and it worked?

Comment: @Laterow Alright, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line that assigns to `c` to this:

```
c <- formula("uhatols ~ x[[1]]")
```

This works because:

1. This will associate the current environment to `c` so `uhatols` will
   be found in the subsequent `lm` call.
2. Since `x` is a data.frame `x[[1]]` refers to the first
   column whereas `x[1]` refers to a one column data frame and these
   are not the same thing.  The relationship can be seen from this:

   ```
   > identical(x[1], data.frame(e = x[[1]]))
   [1] TRUE
   ```

**Note:**  Because the last statement in `test` is an assignment a statement such as

```
test(y, x)
```

will not automatically display its output but if it is assigned it will assign correctly:

```
out <- test(y, x)
out
```

Replace the last statement in the body of `test` with just `lm(c)` if you want it to automatically display output when the call to `test` is not assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This achieves your goal. Note how I use `.` (which means all variables except the y values) in the formula together with the `data` argument of `lm`.

```
test <- function(df, yval = "y") {
  mod1 <- lm(as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ .", yval)), data = df)
  new.df <- data.frame(res = residuals(mod1), 
                       x1 = df[, which.max(names(df) != yval)])
  mod2 <- lm(res ~ x1, data = new.df) 
  mod2
}
x <- data.frame(e=c(1,4,13,2,7,6), f=c(5,9,1,4,3,2))
y <- data.frame(y=c(3,19,1,7,0.2,18))
test(cbind(x, y), "y")
#Call:
#lm(formula = res ~ x1, data = new.df)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1  
# -5.052e-16    9.185e-17
```

Comment: Assuming that you use `cbind(x,y)`, couldn't you just write `x1 = df[,1]`?

Comment: Of course. But I'm always trying to make functions quite general (not important here because "use the first predictor" is not general anyway).

Comment: Thank you @Roland! Laterow's solution is slightly easier for in my opinion though.